# Facebook login user/page identifier

Tags: facebook, user-controls, facebook-java-sdk

Sorry to ask this but browsing the awful Facebook documentation I cannot see the obvious - may to too obvious.

I have a FB application for users to put on their page OK, simple enough etc. but the one thing I cannot find is how to identify the page owner rather than a page visitor.  BY page owner I mean the person who installs the application.

e.g. application name - mytestFBapplication.
You (reader of this question) install the application on your FB page.
All other readers of this question (not you) can visit the page

But as said how do I identify if it is you or me visiting your page.  Reason is if it is you I want to show an admin button and if it is me - guess what, not show the admin button.  For some reason, as said may be obvious and I have missed it somewhere I cannot see this answered anywhere in the facebook documentation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

FQL isAdmin

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_admin/

Old REST API isAdmin

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/pages.isAdmin/

Legacy FBML isAdmin edit Header

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/page-admin-edit-header/